# Is it possible to have an Ocracoke Load Test integrated as part of an MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, ocracoke

I want my load tests to be run as part of my build.  Can I do this with Ocracoke?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Ocracoke, but why don't you look into Visual Studio?

Comment: Ocracoke is the load testing feature that ships with pro versions of VS now.